# This C++ Code Gives a Strange Warning

Tags: c++, structure

I'm programming a simple game. There is a structure I created called "scene". Within the game structure (another structure I created to represent the game state), I call this line of code:

```
scene_container[0].image = " ";
```

I can't figure out why this can't work. Can I even create an array of structures like so:

```
struct scene scene_container[10];
```

When I run the code, this error occurs :

IOS Forbids Declaration of 'scene-container' with no type.

Comment: Where is the strange warning?

Comment: The compiler is giving you an error message. You can start by reading it. If you don't understand what it's saying, post the message here and tell us what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I seem to have forgotten to post the warning. It is IOS Forbids Declaration of scene-container with no type.

Comment: Please include the definition of `struct scene`, and also describe how that first line "can't work" -- what happens when it gets executed?

Comment: in the warning **-** is a typo in 'scene-container' ? You mean its an underscore, right ?

Comment: Yes, there is an underscore between "scene" and "container" in the name of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've prefixed your array reference with a type making it declaration. There is a limit to what you can initialize in declaration (nothing in this case).